# How to run external PHP file using Ajax and display results in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Right now I'm using below script for button click which opens in new window

```
<script>function myFunction()
{
   window.open("ouput.php");
}
</script>
```

But what I need is when user clicks button the results from `output.php` must be appended in the same window at the bottom.
How to execute PHP file using Ajax?
I'm using this code with jQuery but there is no result:

```
$.get( "out.php", 
   function( data ) {          
      document.write(data.Molecule);                  
      $( "output" ).html("Molecule: "+data.Molecule );           
      alert( "Load was performed." );                 
   }, 
   "json" );
});
});
```

How to run an external PHP file, get results and display it in the same webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX calls are regular requests so any PHP file is automatically executed.

`$("output")` will select all `<output>` tags. I suspect you meant an object with ID=output (which is at the bottom of the page)

Here's a corrected js:

```
$.get( "out.php", function( data ) {
    // replace content of #output with the response
    $( "#output" ).html( "Molecule: " + data.Molecule );
    // append the response to #output
    //$( "#output" ).append( "Molecule: " + data.Molecule );
    alert( "Load was performed." );
}, "json" );
```

If the response is not valid JSON this will cause an error (and not call the `alert`). If that's the case you can alert and check the response like this:

```
$.get( "out.php", function( data ) {
    alert( data );
});
```

This won't expect JSON and therefore not throw an error if it's not valid.