# How do I save values in divs in a database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, append

Im currently developing a HTML5 music player with lyrics embedded on the screen, which the users are going to be able to add and sync their own lyrics, mostly for the fun of it. Anyways, I've come pretty far. I've done the player, the controls and I've even done the thing that displays the lyrics and syncs them as well. Here comes the tricky part.

```
$(".newTime").click(function(){
    $( "#nowtime"+onNum ).append( player.currentTime );
    var oldNum = onNum;
    onNum = oldNum + 1;
});
```

This is where I add my code. I press a div, it uses Jquery to append the current time to a div which looks like this `<div class='time' id='nowtime1'></div>`.

This is where I get the song from the database (with help from another fellow stackoverflow user)

```
<?php 
    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM song WHERE id = 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    mysqli_set_charset("utf8");

    $lines = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $row['lyric']);
    $noLines = count($lines);

    array_walk($lines, function(&$line, $idx, $idx) {
      $line = sprintf("<h4 id='no%d'><div class='time' id='nowtime%d'></div>%s</h4>", $idx+1, $idx+1, $line);
    });

    echo implode("\n", $lines);
?>
```

This works totally fine. But, as you can see, when I add the time to the div I add it into a DOM element. I actually add it into multiple DOM elements, because it's multiple lines of text. My question is now, how on earth am I going to input the time in a database and then fetch it again? My idea was to have a column in the table, called `time`. I would then input the text on a row depending on which order it is in `#nowtime`, so if it's `#nowtime1` it would go in the first row and if it's in `#nowtime16` it would be added on the 16th row. Then when you recieve it again, you just add it to the correct div depending on which row it's in.

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it was the only way I came up with.

Comment: Maybe you're running into a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And maybe you're looking for [tag:ajax], but I, for one, cannot understand the logic you're trying to implement and what problem you're running into...

Comment: @brasofilo Sorry, I'm not good at writing questions :P Well, what I really want to have help with is to know how I should save and retrieve the time from the database. When I append to a div, the time stays temporarily, but I need help on how I would save that in the database, and then retrieve it again...

Comment: If you want to get the content of a div (or other dom element), use the jquery .text() function [http://api.jquery.com/text/](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: If you take some time to read the *Linked Articles* inside the [ask] guide, you'll improve a lot when writing questions ;) I was looking some PHP+jQuery questions and found [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23048294/1287812), maybe it helps.

Comment: @ceadreak That might come in useful! I will check it out tomorrow, it's kinda late here :)